# Happy Xmas! WordSearch

Tags: seasonal, word-search

Scrooge Style!

Find these words in the grid:

> - &!*"!^)()\$
> - *%£&*"£^")
> - £*^%%&(!(&
> - !£\$^£*!&"%
> - %\$*)$*&\$^!
> - £%!\$!\$%%\$^
> - ^(!^%*^")(
> - !"\$*&&\$&*\$

[image: symbolsearch]

Comment: are diagonal and backwards allowed? thanks

Comment: FYI, you want to escape your `*` characters, as they're not appearing and italicizing your text when there's 2+ of them. Unless you did that on purpose, then let me know and I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I've got the feeling that there are differences between the image and the printed characters. I couldn't find for example the last sequence but I spotted a similar pattern with different characters.

Comment: @rhsquared that is because the formatting is picking up two * and putting things in italics

Comment: Also I think the second "word" should have a `&` as the second-to-last character instead of a `"`, looks like it might've been off-line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same answer as Greg and gabbo, but I figured I'd post mine because I used a better color than yellow.

Here are all the actual words:

> - &!*"!^)()\$
> - *%£&*"£^&)
> - £*^%%&(!(&
> - !£\$^£*!&"%
> - %\$*)\$*&\$^!
> - £%!\$!\$%%\$^
> - ^(!^%*^")(
> - !"\$*&&\$&*\$

And here is the solution:

> [image: Word Search Solution]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming @Meerkat is correct about the second word:

> [image: words]

Sorry for the poor quality.

Comment: Darn looks like you just beat me

Comment: @gabbo1092, just barely, but yours looks **a lot** cleaner than mine!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the comments are correct and the second word is wrong:

> [image: Solution]